# Oracle ADF When Selecting Multiple Rows, RowSetIterator Does Not Populate on First Method Invocation

Tags: java, javabeans, oracle-adf

Uncertain how best to word the title, but here's the gist.

The goal is to retrieve all selected rows of a table and manipulate them. The problem I'm bumping into is that the RowSetIterator doesn't get populated the first time the method within my backing bean is invoked. It *does* get populated when invoked a second time.

How do I go about getting it to work properly on the first invocation?

Doubtless I'm not being perfectly clear, please let me know if you require any additional information. Here's a snippet of the bean method:

```
  public String deleteSelectedQueries()
  {
    JSFUtils.addInformationMessage("Delete");
    RowKeySet selectedQueries =
      getSavedQueriesByUserTable().getSelectedRowKeys();
    Iterator selectedQueriesIter = selectedQueries.iterator();
    DCBindingContainer bindings =
      (DCBindingContainer) BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
    DCIteratorBinding savedQueriesByUserIter =
      bindings.findIteratorBinding("SavedQueriesByUserROVOIterator");
    RowSetIterator savedQueriesByUserRowSetIterator =
      savedQueriesByUserIter.getRowSetIterator();
    while (selectedQueriesIter.hasNext())
    {
      Key key = (Key) ((List) selectedQueriesIter.next()).get(0);
      Row currentRow = savedQueriesByUserRowSetIterator.getRow(key);
      System.out.println(currentRow.getAttribute("QueryName"));
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This code looks good to me.

The problem may come from `<af:table>` tag, make sure you have  these tags removed:

```
selectedRowKeys="#{bindings.SavedQueriesByUserROVO.collectionModel.selectedRow}"
selectionListener="#{bindings.SavedQueriesByUserROVO.collectionModel.makeCurrent}"
```